# Не работает вызов java из командной строки

Tags: java

Написал простую программу, которая выводит все exe файлы и их размер из директории **c:\windows**:

```
package WorkWithFile_edit;

//import com.beust.jcommander.JCommander;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;



/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */

public class WorkWithFile_edit {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".");
        //System.out.println(path);
        //System.out.println(path.getParent());
        if (args.length==0){
          File folder = new File("C://Windows");

          String[] files = folder.list(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(".exe");
            }

          });

          long file_size_output=0;
         for ( String fileName : files ) {
            File file_size = new File("C://Windows//"+fileName);
            if(file_size.exists()){
                file_size_output=file_size.length();
            }
            System.out.println("File: " + fileName+" Size "+file_size_output+" byte");
        }
      }

    }//end main

}//end class
```

Далее запускаю коммандную строку GIT bash из текущей директории где расположен файл java, выполняю
javac WorkWithFile_edit.java

на выходе у меня создается нормальный class файл, но при попытке, запустить скомпилированный байт код

```
java WorkWithFile_edit
```

вылезает ошибка

> Error: Could not find or load main class

Я понимаю, что эта проблема уже обсуждалась, но решения почему-то на форуме я не смог найти. Предлагаемое решение использовать classpath с указанием текущей директории, тоже пробовал, результат тот же

```
java -cp . WorkWithFile_edit
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

Меня удивляет то, что простая программа HelloWorld.java, нормально компилируется и выполняется без проблем, на том же компьютере, исходник ниже:

```
 class HelloWorld { 
       public static void main(String[] args)
       { System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
       } 
   }
```

Подскажите что я не правильно делаю, и как решить данную ситуацию. Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся.

Comment: [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/312041)

Comment: попробуйте убрать строку `package WorkWithFile_edit;`

Comment: Да если убрать строчку package WorkWithFile_edit; программа через консоль действительно выполняется, но мне надо разобраться как запускать ее именно с указанием пакета, предположим у меня есть директория src а в ней структура
ru/LittleBudda/WorkWithFile_edit.java + в папке src лежит target для откомиллированного java файла
т.е. если я компилирую
javac-d target ru/LittleBudda/WorkWithFile_edit.java
у меня в папке target создается путь ru/LittleBudda в ней лежит откомпилированный класс,

Comment: но потом если я запускаю, коммандую строку и захожу в папку target
java ru/LittleBudda/WorkWithFile
джава машина пишет Error: Could not find or load main class
как правильно запустить в этом случае java файл, если в исходнике указан пакет, спасибо